# Update table based on a Array

Tags: sql, node.js

I have an array

**INPUT -mpg array:**

```
[ { MPG: 'M1', MATNR: '', VOLUME: null,},
  { MPG: 'M2', MATNR: '1111', VOLUME: '9.720' } ]
```

**Table**

[image]

Update Quantity from the volume based on the table key which is MPG and MATNR.

How to form single update statement instead of loop. Kindly suggest .Not sure if its achievable

Code:

```
   `UPDATE STAGING 
         SET QUANTITY = ${mpg[0].VOLUME}
      WHERE (USR21 IN (${mpg.map(x => "'" + x + "'").toString()})
```

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: Oracle..Its only about forming SQL in Node

Comment: ok am not a node guy but still you can try this. const sqlString = `UPDATE STAGING SET QUENTITY = YOURVALUE  WHERE id IN (${array.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  return `${prev},${curr}`;
})})`;
request.query(sqlString);